# How to resolve issue of Bash : cd : too many arguements error?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cd

whenever i command `cd <file/directory>`

it gives output as
`bash:cd:too many arguements`

i am using Bash version 5.0.17 , and often face this issue.

Comment: What does `type cd` output? `bash:cd:too` are there no spaces `bash: cd: ` ? You can't `cd` into a file. And can you give a real command example?

Comment: wrap the path in `" "` i.e. `cd "<directory/path>"` you can't cd to a file as @KamilCuk noted

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to programming?

Comment: Do you have `*` in the path?

Comment: Please type your command literally. If you really type it in your way, `<file/directory` is an input redirction (meaningless to `cd`), and the final `>` is an empty output redirection (error to the shell).

Answer (score 4):

try to quote your directory. Most likely yuo have whitespaces in the name ;)

```
 cd "<file/directory>"
```

See example:

```
$ cd a b
-bash: cd: too many arguments
 $ cd 'a b'
 :~/a b$
```

Comment: It is not working either